# svnadmin dump repopath/* > dumpfile not including all repositories and all revisions

Tags: svn, svnadmin, svndump, svn-repository

I have Subversion installed on Linux (Slackware), and repositories (projects) are in the following path `repopath`.

All individual projects have their own directories (conf, db, hooks, locks). 
Using the command `svnadmin dump repopath/* > svndump.dmp` was making the dump of all projects and all revisions.

Since a new project added using the following command

`svnadmin create newproj`

Nowm when O used `svnadmin dump repopath/*` > svndump.dmp it only makes backup of this newly created project with all it's revisions.

What could go wrong? How to again make backup? of all repositories (projects) and all revisions using a single command `svnadmin dump repopath/* > svndump.dmp`?

Comment: Dump one repo at a time. I'm suprised you even get _one_ repo in there, as here `svnadmin dump somepath/*` here yields the error _"Too many arguments"_ if there is more then one path in there.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you take the dump of one repo at a time. I dont think whatever dump you took after adding new repository would have worked, have you tried loading your dump, I am pretty you wouldnt have worked